# Generate Delight VR virtual tours

Tags: virtual-reality, panoramas, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama, 360-panorama-viewer

Delight VR is a Virtual Reality Player that gives you the tools to build simple [virtual tours](https://delight-vr.com/documentation/dl8-tour/).

This is a code example of a two room tour:

```
<dl8-tour poster="poster.jpg" title="Example Tour 1" author="John Doe"
           start-probe-id="Living Room">

    <dl8-tour-img probe-id="bathroom" title="Bathroom" format="STEREO_360_TB"
                  src="bathroom.jpg">
      <dl8-tour-portal to="living-room" lat="0" lon="270" distance="1.5"
                  title="Enter Living Room"></dl8-tour-portal>
    </dl8-tour-img>

    <dl8-tour-img probe-id="living-room" title="Living Room"
                  format="STEREO_360_TB" src="bathroom.jpg">
      <dl8-tour-portal to="bathroom" lat="0" lon="90" distance="1"
                  title="Go to Bathroom"></dl8-tour-portal>
    </dl8-tour-img>

  </dl8-tour>
```

You just need to copy and paste this on a html file and call their script and you have your tour up and running.

I want to create a tool that generates this kind of "code", a visual interface to build this tours.
Is it possible to use a simple 360º panorama viewer and click on a image, detect the position of the click and convert it then to latitude and longitude to create a "portal" (dl8-tour-portal) and then select another image that would be the destination of that portal? If yes, what would be the 360 panorama viewers that you advise?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you work with equirectangular images this has at least helped me:
FSPViewer is a free viewer for spherical (equirectangular) panoramic images made by Fulvio Senore. http://www.fsoft.it/FSPViewer/
Just see that "Show yaw and pitch in the status bar" in General preferences is checked and that you are not in full screen. And you will get latitude and longitude for the center of the image. You can also "Set View Parameters" in Menu:Tools